# How to clear all of the data in my contract table?

Tags: smart-contract

I know I can user `erase` to clear the table, but this method only clear one data at a time and must write a action to do that. Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following implementation:

```
template<uint64_t A, typename B, typename... C> void clear_table(multi_index<A, B, C...>* table) {
    auto it = table->begin();
    while (it != table->end()) {
        it = table->erase(it);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate about the parameters you are passing, and what they are ?

Comment: @DisplayName, A,B,C are template parameters of multi_index, u can look them up in multi_index.hpp. A - is a table name, B - is a struct, stored in table, C - is indices list. You don't need to pass them, you just pass a table and params will be deducted